# bash sorting by value on linux mount

Tags: bash, sorting, grep

I have this command `df -h|grep -iv filesystem |grep -o "[0-9]\+G"` and the output:

```
19G
14G
6G
9G
9G
3G
9G
247G
43G
192G
```

I need to compare for example bigger than value 10. Could someone give me an idea?

Comment: What are you going to do if you have a filesystem smaller than 1 GB or larger than 1 TB?

Comment: to solve the problem you described in question is relative easy, but I have two questions: 1)your current output is a kind of mixed result of **Size, Used and Avail** filesystems/devices.  is that correct? 2) if there was `250.7G`, your last `grep -o '[0-9]\+G'` will take only `7G` from it, is that what you really want?

Answer (score 4):

Use awk:

```
.... | awk '($1+0)>10'
```

(I added the `+0` so that awk will take only the numerical part (and not the G) in the comparison)

Comment: Good one, this `($1+0)` is a really good solution, because you can keep the "G" info. I like it more than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Given your input, you can for example do:

```
$ df -h .... {your commands} | grep -o [0-9]* a | awk '$1>10'
19
14
247
43
192
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to enter the value of compaction from keyboard for example :

```
./mount_size value ?!
```

where mount_size has :

```
#!bin/bash`df -h|grep -iv filesystem |grep -o "[0-9]\+G"| awk '($1+0)>10'

#
```

What I need  is :
1) sort and print use% and mount using %value for ex 10=value

2) sort and print size and mount using %value for ex 77G=value